# How can I get the total physical memory in C#?

Tags: c#, memory-management

I am using the `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` function to retrieve information about memory, but this function doesn't work correctly. It returns 0 for all properties. I don't think this function works in my Windows 7 environment.

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct MEMORYSTATUSEX
    {
        internal uint dwLength;
        internal uint dwMemoryLoad;
        internal ulong ullTotalPhys;
        internal ulong ullAvailPhys;
        internal ulong ullTotalPageFile;
        internal ulong ullAvailPageFile;
        internal ulong ullTotalVirtual;
        internal ulong ullAvailVirtual;
        internal ulong ullAvailExtendedVirtual;
    }
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool GlobalMemoryStatusEx(ref MEMORYSTATUSEX lpBuffer);

    private void btnGlobalMemoryStatusEX_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MEMORYSTATUSEX statEX = new MEMORYSTATUSEX();
        GlobalMemoryStatusEx(ref statEX);

        double d = (double)statEX.ullTotalPhys;
    }
```

Can anybody tell me where I went wrong with wrong code?

Comment: Have you tried WMI? It is slower, but must work on every OS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I find my mistake from:
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GlobalMemoryStatusEx.html

I Changed

```
internal static extern bool GlobalMemoryStatusEx(ref MEMORYSTATUSEX lpBuffer);
```

To

```
static extern bool GlobalMemoryStatusEx([In, Out] MEMORYSTATUSEX lpBuffer);
```

and changed

```
GlobalMemoryStatusEx(ref statEX);
```

To

```
GlobalMemoryStatusEx(statEX);
```

It work correctly.
Tanks

Comment: how did you get this work. I am running this code in VS run as Admin on Admin account. when i call GlobalMemoryStatusEX() i get an exception  saying: 

System.AccessViolationException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
My.Computer.Info.TotalPhysicalMemory
My.Computer.Info.AvailablePhysicalMemory
```

Comment: tanks, but I write in C#.Net.

Comment: @Amir: Add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.

Comment: @Amir, sorry, I always forget that the My-Namespace does not exist 'natively' in C#. :(

Comment: @Amir: you can still access the property: add a reference to "Microsoft.VisualBasic", then create an instance of the type `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo`. That corresponds to `My.Computer.Info` in @Bobby's answer.

Comment: I did that and i get negative "junk" values. Windows 64 with 8gb ram

Answer (score 5):

If c# you can:

Reference the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly.
Then import `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices` namespace.
And finally use ComputerInfo to get the total physical memory.

```
int bytesPerMebibyte = (1 << 20);  // http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/binary.html
ComputerInfo myCompInfo = new ComputerInfo();
string physicalMemory = "Physical Memory: "
    + (myCompInfo.TotalPhysicalMemory / bytesPerMebibyte) + " MB";
```

Comment: Won't work in .NET Core beause VB is not implemented yet.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this templates:

```
long memory = Process.GetCurrentProcess().PeakVirtualMemorySize64;
```

And another properties with names Peak*64

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about physical memory, so Process isn't that useful.

Comment: Yes, this answer is definitely WRONG. You can delete it.

Comment: @Elmue, please add more details, so I will update the answer.

Comment: It seems that you did not make the effort to read the other answers here. Nor did you read the first comment under your answer. The question is about the TOTAL PHYSICAL memory, which is the amount of RAM installed on the mainboard. Your answer gives the amount of memory that the current PROCESS is consuming. You did not understand the question. Your answer is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set `statEX.dwLength` before calling `GlobalMemoryStatusEx`.

```
MEMORYSTATUSEX statEX = new MEMORYSTATUSEX();
statEX.dwLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX));
GlobalMemoryStatusEx(ref statEX);
```

Comment: Ok, we should set this but the main problem is "ref" keyword. You should remove it from delaretion and usage of function.

Comment: @dalle: fyi because the MEMORYSTATUSEX function is unmanaged, you can use sizeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX) directly, without calling the interop helper (Marshal).