# Get total amount of memory from WinXP and above

Tags: c#, windows, memory, operating-system

There are already many answers about this topic, but is there a single way to get the the total amount of memory on a windows system from XP and above including Windows Server 2003?

What I have found:

[Win32_LogicalMemoryConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394181(v=vs.85).aspx) (Deprecated)

[Win32_ComputerSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(v=vs.85).aspx) (Minimum supported client: Vista)

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.computerinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) (no XP support according to platforms)

thx

Answer (score 0):

Add reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and

```
  var info = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo();
  Debug.WriteLine(info.TotalPhysicalMemory);
  Debug.WriteLine(info.AvailablePhysicalMemory);
  Debug.WriteLine(info.TotalVirtualMemory);
  Debug.WriteLine(info.AvailableVirtualMemory);
```

---

edit : [How can I get the total physical memory in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553336/how-can-i-get-total-physical-memory-in-c)

---

or

You can make use of `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` : [Example Here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.globalmemorystatusex)

```
private void DisplayMemory()
{
    // Consumer of the NativeMethods class shown below
    long tm = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    NativeMethods oMemoryInfo = new NativeMethods();
    this.lblMemoryLoadNumber.Text = oMemoryInfo.MemoryLoad.ToString();
    this.lblIsMemoryTight.Text = oMemoryInfo.isMemoryTight().ToString();
    if (oMemoryInfo.isMemoryTight())
        this.lblIsMemoryTight.Text.Font.Bold = true;
    else
        this.lblIsMemoryTight.Text.Font.Bold = false;

}
```

Native class wrapper.

```
[CLSCompliant(false)]
public class NativeMethods {

     private     MEMORYSTATUSEX msex;
     private uint _MemoryLoad;
     const int MEMORY_TIGHT_CONST = 80;

     public bool isMemoryTight()
      {
         if (_MemoryLoad > MEMORY_TIGHT_CONST )
            return true;
          else
             return false;
     }

          public uint MemoryLoad
     {
        get { return _MemoryLoad; }
         internal set { _MemoryLoad = value; }
      }

       public NativeMethods() {

        msex = new MEMORYSTATUSEX();
        if (GlobalMemoryStatusEx(msex)) {

                  _MemoryLoad = msex.dwMemoryLoad;
             //etc.. Repeat for other structure members        

        }
            else
             // Use a more appropriate Exception Type. 'Exception' should almost never be thrown
             throw new Exception("Unable to initalize the GlobalMemoryStatusEx API");
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    private class MEMORYSTATUSEX
    {
              public uint dwLength;
        public uint dwMemoryLoad;
              public ulong ullTotalPhys;
              public ulong ullAvailPhys;
              public ulong ullTotalPageFile;
              public ulong ullAvailPageFile;
              public ulong ullTotalVirtual;
              public ulong ullAvailVirtual;
              public ulong ullAvailExtendedVirtual;
              public MEMORYSTATUSEX()
        {
                  this.dwLength = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(typeof( MEMORYSTATUSEX ));
        }
    }


     [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
     [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
     static extern bool GlobalMemoryStatusEx( [In, Out] MEMORYSTATUSEX lpBuffer);

}
```

Comment: thx for your answer
Solution #1 shouldn't work under XP
Solution #2 "causes access violation exception on windows xp" and i dont see why System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true); is called