# How to get user mode total virtual memory?

Tags: c#, virtual-address-space, bcdedit, bcdstore

Asking for Win 7/Win 10 (BIOS/EFI). Ive been researching this and havent been able to find a way, heres the story:

In a program I am using `bcdedit /set IncreaseUserVa 3872` to set the user-mode virtual address space to 3872MB, then I restart.

For a unit test I need to check that the change went through using C#. After much research I've tried the following methods:

- [This similar solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553336/how-can-i-get-the-total-physical-memory-in-c). I am getting an exception: `System.AccessViolationException HResult=0x80004003 Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.` I am running VS as admin in the admin account.
- Using `Process.GetCurrentProcess().X`(theres a few memory properties) but those arent for the whole system.
- The BCD reg file in [systemdrive]:/boot contains this data. In regedit HKLM/BCD000000 i cant find anywhere on the web for which reg key to look at
- Importing Microsoft.VisualBasic and use the ComputerInfo class, this one was promising but im setting to 3872MB (3.78GB) and its coming back as ~3GB

Can anyone help? either find the right reg key in BCD000000 or another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

`ComputerInfo myCompInfo = new ComputerInfo();
myCompInfo.TotalVirtualMemory();`

BCDEdit does not allow to set virtual address space over 3GB.